# String "abc" becomes "a\0b\0c\0" after going through Named Pipe from C++ to C# as Unicode

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, visual-studio-2015, named-pipes

I send a message "abc" via a named pipe in C++ (edited for brevity):

```
LPWSTR message = TEXT("abc");
hPipe = CreateFile( // Type: HANDLE
    lpszPipename,   // pipe name 
    GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,              // no sharing 
    NULL,           // default security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
    0,              // default attributes 
    NULL);          // no template file
dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE; // DWORD
SetNamedPipeHandleState(
    hPipe,    // pipe handle 
    &dwMode,  // new pipe mode 
    NULL,     // don't set maximum bytes 
    NULL);    // don't set maximum time 
cbToWrite = (lstrlen(message) + 1)*sizeof(TCHAR); // DWORD
_tprintf(TEXT("%d bytes %s."), cbToWrite, message); // Displays: 8 bytes abc.
WriteFile(
    hPipe,                  // pipe handle 
    message,             // message 
    cbToWrite,              // message length 
    &cbWritten,             // bytes written 
    NULL);                  // not overlapped
```

And receive this message from C#:

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(
    PIPE_NAME,
    PipeDirection.InOut,
    NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
    PipeTransmissionMode.Message
    );
int count = pipeStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
string message= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count); // Same with UTF32
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Console.WriteLine("-" + message+ "-"); // Displays -a b c -
```

**PROBLEM:** Received `message` is `"a\0b\0c\0\0\0"` instead of "abc".
What did I do wrong? I searched all SO tricks for Unicode on C++/C#, to no avail.

Comment: Don't define the macro `UNICODE` in the source, especially after you already have included the header files which uses it. Instead set it in the project settings. You might also want to consider defining `_UNICODE` (apparently [they do slightly different things](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643)).

Comment: LPWSTR is not encoded in utf8, it uses the exact same encoding that C# uses.  Use Encoding.Unicode instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is 2 bytes per character encoding, i.e. 16 bits Unicode. This is something different to UTF8. UTF8 uses as many bytes as needed and thus simple 'a' is one byte, but some Chinese symbols can take e.g. 4 bytes.

You need to use Unicode encoding:

```
string result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, count);
```

Note that this will give you 'abc\0' string, so there will be the null termination, but that is correct.